# Writing my first jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day,

I'm trying to write my first jQuery plugin.  I believe it to be a simple one.  When I focus in on a textbox, I want to remove any currency formatting (i.e. removing '$', ',', and '.')  When I focus out of a textbox, I want to apply numeric comma formatting.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.enableCommify = function() {
        $(this).on('focus', function () {
            var currentValue = $(this).val().trim();
            var stripped = currentValue.replace(',', '');
            $(this).val(stripped);
        });

        $(this).on('focusout', function () {
            var currentValue = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(currentValue.toLocaleString());
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

and when I use it:

```
$('.commify').enableCommify();
```

but it's not working.  What else am I missing?

p.s. I'm aware that there are plugins that do this, I'm just trying to learn how to write one then move on to bigger things.

TIA,

coson

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what is exactly broken? Can you describe it? And have you checked your browser's console for error messages?

Comment: I don't know if it's broken.  I checked the browser console and didn't see any error messages.  Nothing happens.  I expect that when I type 3333, I should see 3,333 when I tab out of the textbox.

Comment: `toLocaleString()` doesn't add commas to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLocaleString()` only adds commas when it's applied to a number. But `$(this).val()` is a string, not a number. Use `parseInt()` to convert it to a number.

Also, to replace multiple matches of a string, you need to use a regexp with the `g` modifier.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.enableCommify = function() {
    $(this).on('focus', function() {
      var currentValue = $(this).val().trim();
      var stripped = currentValue.replace(/,/g, '');
      $(this).val(stripped);
    });

    $(this).on('focusout', function() {
      var currentValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
      $(this).val(currentValue.toLocaleString());
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.commify').enableCommify();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="commify">
```

Comment: Note that `this` is already an instance of jQuery within the plugin function. Using `$(this)` is very inefficient.

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out a couple of minutes ago.  Since you beat me to it, I'll give you the credit anyways.

Comment: I also like the way you did the currentValue.replace.  I also remembered that the replace only does the first replacement and not multiples.  good catch.

Comment: @coson You also have to account for the cursor position change when you change the value after focusing the input. It's annoying